# PHP SQL server query problems

Tags: php

Im using php with mssql function (Xampp). Im trying to do a so-called progress bar for my user to see the process running behind. So, from a form, i send it to two php pages. one is the processing page and another one is the progress bar (popup window) page.

The processing page work fine, insert, update the database. but the problem is another page, which is the progress bar page keep on hang after refresh.

If i run both page using different browser (firefox and chrome), the progress bar working fine, but if both running in the same browser (eg: im using firefox4), the progress bar script will halt and error of 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' appear

fyi, both page use the same database and same table..

many2 thanks in advance....

Comment: This is nothing to do with SQL Server if it works in some cases

Comment: Could you include relevant parts of `progress.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP sessions are known to block other pages accessing the same session concurrently.

Have a look at [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

> but as session data is locked to
>   prevent concurrent writes only one
>   script may operate on a session at any
>   time.

This would explain why accessing the progress bar using a different browser works.

Comment: thx, oredi solve it..
after use this session_write_close, both pages run fine